# Django - How to reload(library) in a django application?

Tags: python, django, shared-libraries, reload

I have a django application which uses a `library.py` file :

**library.py**

```
a=5
```

**View 1:**

```
import library
print library.a  # prints 5
```

On a certain event after updating the `library.py` file and change `a=10`

**View 2:**

```
import library
reload(library) # Should refresh library for the entire project
```

Then I again execute **view 1**:

> It still prints 5, why ?

Can someone explain, since it should have printed `10`, since I updated the value and reloaded the library that was in a shared memory for a `python manage.py runserver`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should refresh library for the entire project

No, it shouldn't. It will reload it in current module only. And don't use it for reloading the code of your project, use the proper way depending on your deployment scheme.

Comment: Why ?
Libraries are shared.. so should reload for all ?

Comment: @YugalJindle No, it shouldn't. It is how `reload` works. And it would be very bad idea to reload it for every module. What if you iterating something from module and in this moment the module is reloaded? You will have a lot of problems. And there are many and many cases like this. And also there are good ways to do reloading (like restaring your dev-server / fcgi process), and no reasons not use them.

Comment: Thanks - I assumed certain stuff. Thanks for the advise as well !